# Getting and posting data to external web API, server-side or client-side?

Tags: javascript, python, flask

I'm working on a web-app which has a section for getting some data from external APIs (e.g. usgs and google-maps) and showing them to the user and another section for getting input from user (e.g. couple of input fields) and posting it to some other API.

I can do the server side using Django/Flask and the client side using Reactjs (or vanilla js, bootstrap, etc).

In 
terms of speed, security and user friendliness, where should I make those API calls? Server side or client side?
Does it make any difference wheter I want to save some of the data to my server or not?

Comment: This is heavily dependent on the use case. Generally I'd say that if the api is public let the client make the calls. It is faster (saves the round-trip between your server and the client) and saves load on your server. If it is a restricted api that requires authentication, e.g. through an API token, this needs to be done by the server. Of course you do not want to leak your private token to all your clients.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Security

In terms of security, if you are doing API calls on server which requires API key then it's not good practice to reveal it in client side. Hence, if that's the case then doing API call in server side will be better option. Apart from that and as per my knowledge there is no security issue in making API calls.

> Speed

In terms of speed,

- If the data to be fetched is common to all the clients, then making API call and cacheing it in server side may increase speed
- For the changes which reflect to client side on real time, API call in server side will lead to page reloading, hence at this point it will be best to do API call in client side
- Sometimes location also matter, like client may be near to the server where API call is being made, at this case it can be faster, but it doesn't help

> User Friendliness

As per the user friendliness, i don't think it matters either way, coz speed is covered. So, apart from that it won't make any difference to client as per my knowledge

Thanks,

*This is just from my point of view and knowledge, if there is more or i am wrong in some point, please correct me*